# C++11 thread support in Qt Creator 2.7.0 (Qt 5.0.2)

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, ubuntu, c++11

I am trying to make threads work in Qt Creator under Ubuntu. I set the

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11 -pthread -lpthread  
CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11 -pthread -lpthread
```

but it still wont work and will write

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of ‘std::system_error’ 
  what(): Operation not permitted
```

The file I try to compile is this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

void fun(){
}

int main()
{
    thread th(&fun);
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: does your installed version of gcc have c++11?

Comment: It does. I have answered my question already, see bellow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to add the following line to the myProject.pro file

```
LIBS += -pthread
```

so it works now with these two lines

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11 
LIBS += -pthread
```

Comment: Interesting, I usually do just "QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11" and that's it

Comment: **Compiler flags != Linker flags** LIBS adds flags to the linker, QMAKE_CXXFLAGS or CXXFLAGS adds flags to the compiler!